# Is it possible to redeploy a Heroku app without restarting some process types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm running a Rails app on Heroku, and I have defined a custom process type to perform some long-running jobs, really long-running, a job can easily take something about an hour or more. I know it's better to split it into some small chunks, but that's quite problematic for that task.

And the issue is that when I push a new version — Heroku restarts all the dynos (web, workers, long workers — everything). I wonder is it possible to restart only some process types, e.g. only the web dynos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that isn't possible. The easiest and most scalable way around this would be to split your long-running jobs into smaller chunks.
That way, you would have a lot of very small jobs being processed very quickly. When your app is restarted, you would be able to restart your process, as it wouldn't stop a long-running job.

Alternatively, [one-off dynos](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos) won't be restarted when your app is deployed.
Using the heroku api, you can programmatically [boot one-off dynos](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#dyno-create). Using that, you could start a one-off dyno for each long-running job you need to process.

That job would be processed (for up to 24 hours, where it would be [cycled](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts)), and you would be able to deploy your app without restarting it.